# Unity tansform.forward how can i use it for going left and right or is there transfrom.left?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject player;
public float moveSpeed = 10f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        player.transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        player.transform.position -= transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        player.transform.position += Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        player.transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

the W and S front and back movements work fine but if I try to use A D which uses vector left and right instead of transform. vector left and vector right change the z position which doesn't work for my project . Is there some way is there anything that i can use to go left or right relative to the direction im facing.

Comment: There's `transform.right`, you can negate it to get the left.

Comment: Unity provides 3 directions (the blue, red, and green arrows) forward, right, and up.  Each can be inverted (using additive inverse) to provide the opposite direction.  You can get Down from Up by inverting Up direction.  Same is true to get Left from Right and Back from Forward.  Looking at the vector (global for simplicity) makes this easy to visualize.  Up is defined as (0, 1, 0) so down would be (0, -1, 0).  Right is (1, 0, 0) so Left is (-1, 0, 0).  Forward is (0, 0, 1) so Back is (0, 0, -1).

Comment: You can also get **any** vector related to the transform using `transform.TransformVector(Vector3.left).normalized` or simply `transform.rotation * Vector3.left`

Answer (score 0):

transform.left can be obtained by negating/flipping [transform.right](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html):

```cs
Vector3 leftDir = -transform.right;
```

You can also use transform.forward and rotate it with Quaternion.

```cs
Vector3 leftDir = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-90, transform.up) *  transform.forward;
```

Comment: Instead of the last thing rather simply do `transform.rotation * Vector3.left` ;) I think this is way better to read ^^

Comment: But not as configurable.

Comment: Are you kidding .. it is completely configurable as you can pass any world space vector and as a result receive a world space vector which is relative to the given transforms local space...